# Could you help me understand the Django ".get_object()" statement in the following code snippet?

Tags: python, django

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
   model = Category

   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
      obj = self.get_object()
      product_set = obj.product_set.all()
      default_product = obj.default_category.all()
      products = (product_set | default_products).distinct()
      context["products"] = products
      return context
```

I don't understand which object is being returned?

From the above, it appears that the "Category" model object would be returned, but what's interesting is that the "Category" model is not connected to a "Product" model (there is no explicit FK in the Product model), which is referenced immediately after the object is defined - by the obj.product_set.all() code.

```
class Category(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   slug = models.SlugField()
   description = models.TextField()
   active = model.BooleanField()
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

A "Product" model also exists, defined below -

```
class Product(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
```

It seems this ManyToManyField reference is what's being called by "product_set" but I wanted to be absolutely sure as this code paradigm seems difficult to read when there's no explicit reference in the Category model to Product.

Comment: Please read the manual about [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) and [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object): "Returns the single object that this view will display. If queryset is provided, that queryset will be used as the source of objects; otherwise, get_queryset() will be used."

Comment: It becomes clearer when you combine it with the associated url

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've expanded the original question.I did read the documentation before asking the above question but what's not clear is the content I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [Many to Many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships)

> The only difference is in the attribute naming: The model that defines the ManyToManyField uses the attribute name of that field itself, whereas the “reverse” model uses the lowercased model name of the original model, **plus '_set'** (just like reverse one-to-many relationships).

(Emphasis mine)

So yes, its one of djangos cool little features, whenever there is a many relationship, adding `_set` will query objects that have a "one/many to many" relationship with the caller.